# Making my ASP.NET website compatible with Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, firefox

I have an ASP.net website ( http://www.erate.co.za ) version 2.0.
When someone opens my website in Firefox everything looks different.

Why is that and how can I make it compatible?

Please help!

Etienne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problems don't have anything to do with ASP.NET / C# Specifically.

They have to do with your understanding of web design / HTML / CSS and how you can make a cross-browser compatible UI.

I'd suggest you look at http://www.w3schools.com/ for some information on good web design practices.

Some obvious problems with the Source that you need to address are

- No common css Stylesheets
- Styles are applied inline on lots of elements
- using long strings of "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" to align text

Answer (score 3):

The underlying server technology should not have any impact on your websites appearence as long as you are just producing HTML.
What you need to do is make sure that your HTML and CSS works as intended in all browsers. A good way to start is to make sure that you only output standards compliant code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is that styles that you are using don't work in firefox such as cursor:hand; versus cursor:pointer;  both work in IE but only pointer works in firefox.  A quick recommendation would be to just run the resultant page through the w3c validator located at:  http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Per se, ASP.NET produce vanilla HTML/Javascript, so there's nothing wrong with the technology.

Focus on the html, try to be as close as possible to the [w3c standards](http://validator.w3.org/), it should help a lot.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), an incredible web dev extension for Firefox should also help you a lot in debugging your CSS.

It might be a painful task, especially if your site is old and big. Good luck!